# Content type going wrong in the POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

This is how I am sending my POST request:

```
{if (![[NetworkManager sharedManager] connected]) {

    [[NetworkManager sharedManager].requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [NetworkManager sharedManager].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

    [[NetworkManager sharedManager] POST:url parameters:param progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        if (responseObject != nil) {
             NSLog(@"JSON === %@",responseObject);
            successBlock(responseObject,task);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            failureBlock(error,task);
        }
    }];
}else
{
    failureBlock(nil,nil);

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow makeToast:@"Please check your internet connection"
                                                          duration:2.0
                                                          position:CSToastPositionBottom];
        });

}}
```

But I am getting an error that **"Request failed: unacceptable content type: text/html".** I am using `AFNetworking`. Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

@Ghazalah try this..

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:url parameters:dictParam progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)
         {

         } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
         {
             DLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
             if (dataBlock)
             {
                 if(responseObject==nil)
                     dataBlock(task.response,nil);
                 else
                     dataBlock(responseObject,nil);
             }
         } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error)
         {
             DLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             if (dataBlock) {
                 dataBlock(nil,error);
             }
         }];
```

Comment: still giving: "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

Comment: can you provide me url ? so i can check that

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened when your server is sending @"text/html" instead of the already supported types(@"application/json"). My solution was to add "text/html" to acceptableContentTypes set in AFURLResponseSerialization class. Just search for "acceptableContentTypes" and add @"text/html" to the set manually.

```
    {
    if (![[NetworkManager sharedManager] connected]) {

        [[NetworkManager sharedManager].requestSerializer setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [NetworkManager sharedManager].responseSerializer.acceptableC‌ontentTypes = [[NetworkManager sharedManager].responseSerializer.acceptable‌​ContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

        [[NetworkManager sharedManager] POST:url parameters:param progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
            if (responseObject != nil) {
                NSLog(@"JSON === %@",responseObject);
                successBlock(responseObject,task);
            }
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                failureBlock(error,task);
            }
        }];
    }
    else{
        failureBlock(nil,nil);

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow makeToast:@"Please check your internet connection"
            duration:2.0 position:CSToastPositionBottom];
        });

    }
}
```

The ideal solution is to change the type sent from the server, but for that, you will have to talk with the server team.